# Getting EF 4.1 Code First project working

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am building a simple application with EF 4.1 Code First, but I am stuck. Here's an ERD of my application Domain Model:

[image]

In Visual Studio 2010, I have a solution with two projects in it. One project is to house the Domain Model, the other is an MVC3 Web Application to house the application logic.

In the Class Libraries (Project 1), I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace QuotesDomain
{
    public class QuoteContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public DbSet<QTBridge> QTBridge { get; set; }
    }

    public class Quote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(500)]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public int Likes { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool isApproved { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QTBridge> TagsBridge { get; set; }
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(30), MinLength(2)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(30), MinLength(2)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOD { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(60), MinLength(2)]
        public string Occupation { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(170), MinLength(5)]
        public string WikiLink { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool isApproved { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Language
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(20), MinLength(2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(40), MinLength(2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QTBridge> QuotesBridge { get; set; }
    }

    public class QTBridge
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int QuoteId { get; set; }
        public int TagId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've been watching some video tutorials, and the above looks good to me, but when I try and run the application, I get the following error:

[image]

Are my Code First classes correct based on the ERD Diagram? What do I need to do to solve the error?

Comment: article about composite keys http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/02/01/composite-keys-are-evil/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the full listing of code for Entities and configuration.

```
public class QuoteContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //This will create create a join table "QuoteTags"
        modelBuilder.Entity<Quote>().HasMany(q => q.Tags)
            .WithMany(t => t.Quotes);
    }
}

public class Quote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(500)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int Likes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LanguageId")]
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(30), MinLength(2)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(30), MinLength(2)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    public DateTime DOD { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(60), MinLength(2)]
    public string Occupation { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(170), MinLength(5)]
    public string WikiLink { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(20), MinLength(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(40), MinLength(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Quote> Quotes{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eranga. I have gone ahead and added the [ virtual ] keyword to navigational properties.

I'm still slightly confused about the ForeignKey though. All I want to do is have a Composite key of Quote.Id and Tag.Id .. what is the best way to achieve that.

Thank You.

Comment: @Ciwan Attribute based configuration(as you have done above) or Fluent API can be used to configure your model. It is just a matter of choice as which to use.

Comment: I went ahead and added the QTBridge code you have provided in your answer, but it is still not working, I get the following error, and I'm not sure how to proceed. :(

1[Composite Key Error](http://i54.tinypic.com/efs20y.jpg)

Comment: @Ciwan when using ORM you should generally not use Composite key, it will make life much easier if you give QTBridge
 its own primary key

Comment: Thanks Daveo, I've just noticed the relations lines are the wrong way on the Many-to-Many relation in my ERD diagram.

I have gone ahead and did as you suggested Daveo, but now I get a very ![vague error](http://i51.tinypic.com/2r753t4.jpg) !

Comment: @Ciwan You do not need to model the `QTBridge`. `Quote` class should have a 'Tag` collection and `Tag` class should have `Quote` collection.

Comment: @Eranga, I'm confused now :( My lecturer at Uni always said I needed an Extra table (bridge) for Many-to-Many relationships !

As for the vague error, I dug further in, and it the error says:

"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated."

I don't have a DateTime2 datatype !! :s

Comment: @Ciwan for Many-to-Many you need a join table. But you do not need to model that table as a class.

Comment: Oh so how do I go about it ? or does it automatically get created ?

Comment: Thank You Eranga, it seems to be working now. **Thank You soo much**. I am trying to Vote Up but it says I need 15 reputation points :(

I have marked post as useful.